# How to remove lines from output containing a particular string?

Tags: command-line

I am trying to find the latest modified files in my system say in the last 2 hours or so. The command that I am using is:

```
sudo find / -mmin -120 -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -n | cut -f2- -d" " | more
```

But the above command outputs a lot of entries that contain the string `/proc`. So, are there any better ways by which I can remove those lines from the output?

Also, if you have any better methods to deal with the above situation then please suggest. The only criteria is that the output should contain files as well as directories.

---

**EDIT:-**

I modified the above command to also include names with `newline`, then added [Arronical's](https://askubuntu.com/a/825232/119531) answer and [αғsнιη's](https://askubuntu.com/a/825235/119531) answer to it. The final outcome is:

```
sudo find / ! -path '*/proc*' -type f -mmin -120 -exec ls -al {} \; | grep -v anystring | less
```

Comment: Do the lines all start with `/proc`?

Comment: @Arronical - Yes.

Comment: Pipe it through `grep -v /proc`.

Comment: Please don't [parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). It isn't even helping here. GNU `find` already has an `ls` option that does pretty much the same thing as `ls -al`. In any case, file names with newlines aren't a problem here, not if you just want to see the list. So just do `sudo find / ! -path '*/proc*' -type f -mmin -120  | less`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `grep -v` to remove lines containing a string, such as '/proc', you could add this as a pipe to your command to make:

```
sudo find / -mmin -120 -printf '%T@ %p\n' | grep -v '^/proc' | sort -n | cut -f2- -d" " | more
```

However, as files in `/proc/` are transitory in nature, you'll be likely to get some errors like

```
find: â?~/proc/22232/fdinfo/5â?T: No such file or directory
```

You can avoid these by redirecting the STDERR of the find command to `/dev/null` using, `2>/dev/null` like so:

```
sudo find / -mmin -120 -printf '%T@ %p\n' 2>/dev/null | grep -v '^/proc' | sort -n | cut -f2- -d" " | more
```

**A Better Method**

Rather than filtering the results, and getting rid of your error messages, you can alter your find command so that it never looks in `/proc`:

```
sudo find / -not -path '/proc/*' -mmin -120 -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -n | cut -f2- -d" " | more
```

Comment: I fixed a missing single quote and anchored your pattern to the beginning of the line to prevent unwanted matches.

Comment: Thanks @ByteCommander, I think modifying the find command is a better solution anyway, just figuring out how.

Comment: There is the `-prune` option to exclude directories, but it seems not to work well together with other filters...

Answer (score 5):

I would use `-prune` for this kind of thing e.g.

```
find / \( -path /proc -o -path /sys -o -path /run \) -prune -o -mmin -120 -printf '%T@ %p\n'
```

Comment: I'd been trying to use prune, but with `-name` rather than `-path`, or with `-path` but a trailing slash, oops!

Answer (score 2):

You can exclude the '/proc' path as following,

```
[sudo] find / ! -path "/proc" ...
```

to exclude 'proc' entries in any level of path, use like below

```
[sudo] find / ! -path "*/proc/*" ...
```